# In PyTorch how are layer weights and biases initialized by default?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I was wondering how are layer weights and biases initialized by default? E.g. if I create the linear layer
     torch.nn.Linear(5,100)
How are weights and biases for this layer initialized by default?

Answer (score 8):

**PyTorch 1.0**

Most layers are initialized using [Kaiming Uniform](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_) method. Example layers include Linear, Conv2d, RNN etc. If you are using other layers, you should look up that layer on [this doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#convolution-layers). If it says weights are initialized using `U(...)` then its Kaiming Uniform method. Bias is initialized using [LeCunn init](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf), i.e., `uniform(-std, std)` where standard deviation std is `1/sqrt(fan_in)` ([code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.0.0/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L45)).

**PyTorch 0.4.1, 0.3.1**

Weights and biases are initialized using [LeCunn init](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) (see sec 4.6) for conv layers (code: [0.3.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v0.3.1/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L40), [0.4.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v0.4.1/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L40)).

If you want to override default initialization then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433937/207661).

Comment: Has this changed? I mean was it not the case for Pytorch 0.3 until now?

Comment: Yes, this is changed in 1.0. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The weights are initilized in the following way:

```
def reset_parameters(self):
    stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(self.weight.size(1))
    self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
    if self.bias is not None:
        self.bias.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
```

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L48-L52