# How do I initialize weights in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

How do I initialize weights and biases of a network (via e.g. He or Xavier initialization)?

Comment: PyTorch often initializes the weights [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773737/365102).

Answer (score 343, accepted):

## Single layer

To initialize the weights of a single layer, use a function from [`torch.nn.init`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.init.html). For instance:

```
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(...)
torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(conv1.weight)
```

Alternatively, you can modify the parameters by writing to `conv1.weight.data` (which is a [`torch.Tensor`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor)). Example:

```
conv1.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
```

The same applies for biases:

```
conv1.bias.data.fill_(0.01)
```

### `nn.Sequential` or custom `nn.Module`

Pass an initialization function to [`torch.nn.Module.apply`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.apply). It will initialize the weights in the entire `nn.Module` recursively.

> **apply(*fn*):** Applies `fn` recursively to every submodule (as returned by `.children()`) as well as self. Typical use includes initializing the parameters of a model (see also torch-nn-init).

Example:

```
def init_weights(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(m.weight)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.Linear(2, 2))
net.apply(init_weights)
```

Comment: I found a `reset_parameters` method in the source code of many modules. Should I override the method for weight initialization?

Comment: what if I want to use a Normal distribution with some mean and std?

Comment: What is the default initialization if I don't specify one?

Comment: `nn.init.xavier_uniform` is now deprecated in favor of `nn.init.xavier_uniform_`

Comment: @xjcl The [default initialization](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L96) for a `Linear` layer is `init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))`.

Comment: Can you use a lambda here instead of a def'ing a function?

Comment: Link to nn.Module.apply docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/1.13/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.apply

Comment: I think it is also important to understand that as mentioned in the answer _.apply()_ function is using _.children()_ method and not the _.parameters()_ method. Which is why in the applied _init\_weights(m)_ function we can use _isinstance(m, nn.Linear)_ to figure out which layer we are applying it to. A clarification on their difference can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465723/what-is-the-difference-between-parameters-and-children .

Comment: Note from a few years later: using .data is discouraged these days. E.g. see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-tensor-data/79640/4

Answer (score 104):

### We compare different mode of weight-initialization using the same neural-network(NN) architecture.

#### All Zeros or Ones

If you follow the principle of [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor), you might think setting all the weights to 0 or 1 would be the best solution.  This is not the case.

With every weight the same, all the neurons at each layer are producing the same output.  This makes it hard to decide which weights to adjust.

```
    # initialize two NN's with 0 and 1 constant weights
    model_0 = Net(constant_weight=0)
    model_1 = Net(constant_weight=1)
```

- After 2 epochs:

[image: plot of training loss with weight initialization to constant]

```
Validation Accuracy
9.625% -- All Zeros
10.050% -- All Ones
Training Loss
2.304  -- All Zeros
1552.281  -- All Ones
```

#### Uniform Initialization

A [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution) has the equal probability of picking any number from a set of numbers.

Let's see how well the neural network trains using a uniform weight initialization, where `low=0.0` and `high=1.0`.

Below, we'll see another way (besides in the Net class code) to initialize the weights of a network. To define weights outside of the model definition, we can:

> 1. Define a function that assigns weights by the type of network layer, *then*
> 2. Apply those weights to an initialized model using `model.apply(fn)`, which applies a function to each model layer.

```
    # takes in a module and applies the specified weight initialization
    def weights_init_uniform(m):
        classname = m.__class__.__name__
        # for every Linear layer in a model..
        if classname.find('Linear') != -1:
            # apply a uniform distribution to the weights and a bias=0
            m.weight.data.uniform_(0.0, 1.0)
            m.bias.data.fill_(0)

    model_uniform = Net()
    model_uniform.apply(weights_init_uniform)
```

- After 2 epochs:

[image]

```
Validation Accuracy
36.667% -- Uniform Weights
Training Loss
3.208  -- Uniform Weights
```

### General rule for setting weights

The general rule for setting the weights in a neural network is to set them to be close to zero without being too small.

> Good practice is to start your weights in the range of [-y, y] where `y=1/sqrt(n)`
>   (n is the number of inputs to a given neuron).

```
    # takes in a module and applies the specified weight initialization
    def weights_init_uniform_rule(m):
        classname = m.__class__.__name__
        # for every Linear layer in a model..
        if classname.find('Linear') != -1:
            # get the number of the inputs
            n = m.in_features
            y = 1.0/np.sqrt(n)
            m.weight.data.uniform_(-y, y)
            m.bias.data.fill_(0)

    # create a new model with these weights
    model_rule = Net()
    model_rule.apply(weights_init_uniform_rule)
```

below we compare performance of NN, weights initialized with uniform distribution [-0.5,0.5) versus the one whose weight is initialized using **general rule**

- After 2 epochs:

[image: plot showing performance of uniform initialization of weight versus general rule of initialization]

```
Validation Accuracy
75.817% -- Centered Weights [-0.5, 0.5)
85.208% -- General Rule [-y, y)
Training Loss
0.705  -- Centered Weights [-0.5, 0.5)
0.469  -- General Rule [-y, y)
```

### normal distribution to initialize the weights

> The normal distribution should have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of `y=1/sqrt(n)`, where n is the number of inputs to NN

```
    ## takes in a module and applies the specified weight initialization
    def weights_init_normal(m):
        '''Takes in a module and initializes all linear layers with weight
           values taken from a normal distribution.'''

        classname = m.__class__.__name__
        # for every Linear layer in a model
        if classname.find('Linear') != -1:
            y = m.in_features
        # m.weight.data shoud be taken from a normal distribution
            m.weight.data.normal_(0.0,1/np.sqrt(y))
        # m.bias.data should be 0
            m.bias.data.fill_(0)
```

below we show the performance of two NN one initialized using **uniform-distribution** and the other using **normal-distribution**

- After 2 epochs:

[image: performance of weight initialization using uniform-distribution versus the normal distribution]

```
Validation Accuracy
85.775% -- Uniform Rule [-y, y)
84.717% -- Normal Distribution
Training Loss
0.329  -- Uniform Rule [-y, y)
0.443  -- Normal Distribution
```

Comment: What is the task you optimize for? And how can an all zeros solution give zero loss?

Comment: @ashunigion I think you misrepresent what Occam says: "entities should not be multiplied without necessity". He does not say you should pick up the simplest approach. If that was the case, then you should not have used a neural network in the first place.

Comment: If you follow occam’s razor, you  may also want to consider gaussian initialization, since that is  the distribution with the highest entropy (for given variance), ie the "least informative"

Answer (score 55):

**To initialize layers, you typically don't need to do anything.**

PyTorch will do it for you. If you think about it, this makes a lot of sense. Why should we initialize layers, when PyTorch can do that following the latest trends?

For instance, the [`Linear`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/af7dc23124a6e3e7b8af0637e3b027f3a8b3fb76/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L101) layer's `__init__` method will do [Kaiming He](http://kaiminghe.com/) initialization:

```
init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
if self.bias is not None:
    fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
    bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in) if fan_in > 0 else 0
    init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)
```

Similarly, this holds for other layers types. For e.g., `Conv2d`, check [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/029a968212b018192cb6fc64075e68db9985c86a/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L49).

**NOTE:** The advantage of proper initialization is faster training speed. If your problem requires special initialization, you can still do it afterwards.

Comment: The default initialization doesn't always give the best results, though. I recently implemented the VGG16 architecture in Pytorch and trained it on the CIFAR-10 dataset, and I found that just by switching to `xavier_uniform` initialization for the weights (with biases initialized to 0), rather than using the default initialization, my validation accuracy after 30 epochs of RMSprop increased from 82% to 86%. I also got 86% validation accuracy when using Pytorch's built-in VGG16 model (not pre-trained), so I think I implemented it correctly. (I used a learning rate of 0.00001.)

Comment: This is because they haven't used Batch Norms in VGG16. It is true that proper initialization matters and that for some architectures you pay attention. For instance, if you use (nn.conv2d(), ReLU() sequence) you will init  Kaiming He initialization designed for relu your conv layer. PyTorch cannot predict your activation function after the conv2d. This make sense if you evaluate the eignevalues, but *typically* you don't have to do much if you use Batch Norms, they will normalize outputs for you. If you plan to win to SotaBench competition it matters.

Answer (score 16):

```
import torch.nn as nn        

# a simple network
rand_net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features, h_size),
                         nn.BatchNorm1d(h_size),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(h_size, h_size),
                         nn.BatchNorm1d(h_size),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Linear(h_size, 1),
                         nn.ReLU())

# initialization function, first checks the module type,
# then applies the desired changes to the weights
def init_normal(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear:
        nn.init.uniform_(m.weight)

# use the modules apply function to recursively apply the initialization
rand_net.apply(init_normal)
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want some extra flexibility, **you can also set the weights manually**.

Say you have input of all ones:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

input = torch.ones((8, 8))
print(input)
```

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

And you want to make a dense layer with no bias (so we can visualize):

```
d = nn.Linear(8, 8, bias=False)
```

Set all the weights to 0.5 (or anything else):

```
d.weight.data = torch.full((8, 8), 0.5)
print(d.weight.data)
```

The weights:

```
Out[14]: 
tensor([[0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]])
```

All your weights are now 0.5. Pass the data through:

```
d(input)
```

```
Out[13]: 
tensor([[4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]], grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
```

Remember that each neuron receives 8 inputs, all of which have weight 0.5 and value of 1 (and no bias), so it sums up to 4 for each.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry for being so late, I hope my answer will help.

To initialise weights with a `normal distribution` use:

```
torch.nn.init.normal_(tensor, mean=0, std=1)
```

Or to use a `constant distribution` write:

```
torch.nn.init.constant_(tensor, value)
```

Or to use an `uniform distribution`:

```
torch.nn.init.uniform_(tensor, a=0, b=1) # a: lower_bound, b: upper_bound
```

You can check other methods to initialise tensors [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch-nn-init)

Answer (score 7):

## Iterate over parameters

If you cannot use `apply` for instance if the model does not implement `Sequential` directly:

### Same for all

```
# see UNet at https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet/tree/master/unet


def init_all(model, init_func, *params, **kwargs):
    for p in model.parameters():
        init_func(p, *params, **kwargs)

model = UNet(3, 10)
init_all(model, torch.nn.init.normal_, mean=0., std=1) 
# or
init_all(model, torch.nn.init.constant_, 1.)
```

### Depending on shape

```
def init_all(model, init_funcs):
    for p in model.parameters():
        init_func = init_funcs.get(len(p.shape), init_funcs["default"])
        init_func(p)

model = UNet(3, 10)
init_funcs = {
    1: lambda x: torch.nn.init.normal_(x, mean=0., std=1.), # can be bias
    2: lambda x: torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(x, gain=1.), # can be weight
    3: lambda x: torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(x, gain=1.), # can be conv1D filter
    4: lambda x: torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(x, gain=1.), # can be conv2D filter
    "default": lambda x: torch.nn.init.constant(x, 1.), # everything else
}

init_all(model, init_funcs)
```

You can try with `torch.nn.init.constant_(x, len(x.shape))` to check that they are appropriately initialized:

```
init_funcs = {
    "default": lambda x: torch.nn.init.constant_(x, len(x.shape))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the better way, just pass your whole model

```
import torch.nn as nn
def initialize_weights(model):
    # Initializes weights according to the DCGAN paper
    for m in model.modules():
        if isinstance(m, (nn.Conv2d, nn.ConvTranspose2d, nn.BatchNorm2d)):
            nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
        # if you also want for linear layers ,add one more elif condition
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuz I haven't had the enough reputation so far, I can't add a comment under

> the answer posted by *prosti* in *Jun 26 '19 at 13:16*.

```py
    def reset_parameters(self):
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(3))
        if self.bias is not None:
            fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
            bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
            init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)
```

But I wanna point out that actually we know some assumptions in the paper of *Kaiming He*, *Delving Deep into Rectifiers: Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification*, are not appropriate, though it looks like the deliberately designed initialization method makes a hit in practice.

E.g., within the subsection of *Backward Propagation Case*, they assume that $w_l$ and $\delta y_l$ are independent of each other. But as we all known, take the score map $\delta y^L_i$ as an instance, it often is $y_i-softmax(y^L_i)=y_i-softmax(w^L_ix^L_i)$ if we use a typical cross entropy loss function objective.

So I think the true underlying reason why *He's Initialization* works well remains to unravel. Cuz everyone has witnessed its power on boosting deep learning training.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a deprecation warning (@Fábio Perez)...

```
def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear:
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.Linear(2, 2))
net.apply(init_weights)
```

Comment: You can comment over there at [Fábio Perez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433937/8608146) to keep the answers clean.