# what is the default weight initializer for conv in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, initializer

The question [How to initialize weights in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433936/how-to-initialize-weights-in-pytorch) shows how to initialize the weights in `Pytorch`.  However, what is the default weight initializer for `Conv`and `Dense` in `Pytorch`? What distribution does `Pytorch` use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each `pytorch` layer implements the method `reset_parameters` which is called at the end of the layer initialization to initialize the weights.
You can find the implementation of the layers [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch/nn/modules).

For the dense layer which in pytorch is called `linear` for example, weights are initialized uniformly

```
stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(self.weight.size(1))
self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
```

where `self.weight.size(1)` is the number of inputs. This is done to keep the variance of the distributions of each layer relatively similar at the beginning of training by normalizing it to one. You can read a more detailed explanation [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init).

For the convolutional layer the initialization is basically the same. You just compute the number of inputs by multiplying the number of channels with the kernel size.