# What is the difference between parameters and children?

Tags: pytorch

It looks like `parameters` and `children` show the same info, so what is the difference between them?

```
import torch

print('torch.__version__', torch.__version__)

m = torch.load('imagenet_resnet18.pth')

print(m.parameters)
print(m.children)
```

Answer (score 9):

- `model.parameters()` is a generator that returns tensors containing your model parameters.
- `model.children()` is a generator that returns layers of the model from which you can extract your parameter tensors using `<layername>.weight` or `<layername>.bias`

Visit this [link](https://github.com/mortezamg63/Accessing-and-modifying-different-layers-of-a-pretrained-model-in-pytorch) for a simple tutorial on accessing and freezing model layers.

Answer (score 2):

The (only, during my writing) [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717992/5290519) is not to the point, and thus misleading in my own opinion. By the current docs(08/23/2022):

- [`children()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.children):

  > Returns an iterator over **immediate** children modules.

  This should mean that it will stop at non-leaf node like `torch.nn.Sequential`, `torch.nn.ModuleList`, etc.
- [`parameters(recurse=True)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters):

  > Returns an iterator over module parameters. This is typically **passed to an optimizer**.

  "Passed to an optimizer" should imply that recursive cases are taken care by the team. Just pass the return value/object to the optimizer.

Since I know you're lazy developers, you must read this answer from PyTorch forum to see the output of `children()` done by someone: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/module-children-vs-module-modules/4551/4?u=raining_day513