# what is the first initialized weight in pytorch convolutional layer

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I do self-studying in [Udacity PyTorch](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud188/lessons/b1e148af-0beb-464e-a389-9ae293cb1dcd/concepts/ee871bfb-1818-49f8-ada6-41d5f3824aac)
Regarding to the last paragraph

> Learning
>
> In the code you've been working with, you've been setting the values of filter weights explicitly, but neural networks will actually learn the best filter weights as they train on a set of image data. You'll learn all about this type of neural network later in this section, but know that high-pass and low-pass filters are what define the behavior of a network like this, and you know how to code those from scratch!
>
> In practice, you'll also find that many neural networks learn to detect the edges of images because the edges of object contain valuable information about the shape of an object.

I have studied all through the last 44th sections. But I couldn't be able to answer the following questions

1. What is the initialized weight when I do `torch.nn.Conv2d`? And how to define it myself?
2. How does `PyTorch` update weights in the convolutional layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declared `nn.Conv2d` the weights are initialized via this [code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/conv.html#_ConvNd).

In particular, if you give bias it uses initialization as proposed by Kaiming et.al. It initializes as uniform distribution between (-bound, bound) where `bound=\sqrt{6/((1+a^2)fan_in)}` (See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_)).

You can initialize weight manually too. This has been answered elsewhere (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433937/3236925)) and I won't repeat it.

When you call `optimizer.step` and optimizer has parameters of convolutional filter registered they are updated.

Answer (score 0):

1.In PyTorch, Conv2d is designed to accept 4D Tensor of shape (N, C, H, W) as an input for forward pass, where N is the number of samples in mini-batch, C is the number of input channels (for example 3 color channel of an image), H and W are height and width of an image.

Your weights should reflect that and be 4D Tensor of shape (F, C, K_H, K_W) where F would be the number of different kernels you would like to have in this layer, C is the number of input channels, K_H and K_W are height and width of kernels. Exact values of initialization can be computed using formula in PyTorch docs, nn.Conv2d definition.

Here is a great figure which will help to visualize computation.
[Cross-correlation computation with 2 input channels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDYs5.png)  Ref. http://www.d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-neural-networks/channels.html, Fig. 6.4.1

2.Weights are updated using back propagation algorithm by calculating gradients. It is executed under the hood in PyTorch. If you are initializing weights yourself, you should add `requires_grad=True` for the weight tensor to specifically say that this tensor should be updated by back propagation.