# How can I write the below equivalent code of Keras Neural Net in Pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, pytorch

How can I write the below equivalent code of Keras Neural Net in Pytorch?

```
actor = Sequential()
        actor.add(Dense(20, input_dim=9, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        actor.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
        actor.add(Dense(27, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        actor.summary()
        # See note regarding crossentropy in cartpole_reinforce.py
        actor.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=Adam(lr=self.actor_lr))[Please find the image eq here.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJviP.png
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Similiar questions have already been asked, but here it goes:

```
import torch

actor = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(9, 20), # output shape has to be specified
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(20, 20), # same goes over here
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(20, 27), # and here
    torch.nn.Softmax(),
)

print(actor)
```

**Initialization**: By default, from version 1.0 onward, linear layers will be initialized with **Kaiming Uniform** (see [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-default-initialization-methods-for-layers/3157/21)). If you want to initialize your weights differently, see most upvoted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433936/how-to-initialize-weights-in-pytorch).

You may also use Python's `OrderedDict` to match certain layers easier, see [Pytorch's documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433936/how-to-initialize-weights-in-pytorch), you should be able to proceed from there.