# What can I use in Pytorch to remplace caffe's weight filler

Tags: python, model, pytorch, caffe

I'm writing a pytorch model based on the caffe model below. Do you know how I can write weight filler and bias filler in pytorch ?

```
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad_h: 0
    pad_w: 1
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytorch has [`torch.nn.init`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html) library to help with init weights of a network.
You probably want to use [`nn.init.normal_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.normal_) for the `"gaussian"` filler, and [`nn.init.constant_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.constant_) for the `"constant"` filler of the bias.

You can use a function to fill the weights of a module `m`:

```py
def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Conv2d:
        torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight, std=0.1)
        if m.bias is not None:
            torch.nn.init.constant_(m.bias, val=0)

# define the net
net = MyCaffeLikeNetwork()
# use the function to init all weights of the net
net.apply(init_weights)
```

For more information on weight init in pytorch you can look at [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433937/1714410).