# Why torch.nn.Conv2d has different result between '(n, n)' and 'n' arguments?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
input = torch.randn(8, 3, 50, 100)

m = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=(1, 1))
m2 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

output = m(input)
output2 = m2(input)

torch.equal(output, output2) >> False
```

I suppose above m and m2 Conv2d should have exactly same output value but practically not, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialized two `nn.Conv2d` with identical settings, that's true. Initialization of the weights however is done randomly! You have here two different layers `m` and `m2`. Namely `m.weight` and `m2.weigth` have different components, same goes for `m.bias` and `m2.bias`.

One way to have get the same results, is to copy the underlying parameters of the model:

```
>>> m.weight = m2.weight
>>> m.bias = m2.bias
```

Which, of course, results in `torch.equal(m(input), m2(input))` being `True`.

Comment: Thanks, after m.weight = m2.weight, the Conv2d result are identical

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" here isn't related to `int` vs `tuple`. In fact, if you print `m` and `m2`  you'll see

```py
>>> m
Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>>> m2
Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
```

that the integer got expanded as the documentation promises.

What actually differs is the initial weights, which I believe are just random. You can view them via `m.weights`, `m2.weights`. These will differ every time you create a new `Conv2d`, even if you use the same arguments.

You can initialize the weights if you want to play around with these objects in a predictable way, see
[How to initialize weights in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433936/how-to-initialize-weights-in-pytorch)
e.g.

```py
m.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
m2.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
m.bias.data.fill_(0.1)
m2.bias.data.fill_(0.1)
```

and they should now be identical.