Loading partial weights of a neural network
I'm working on a Deep Learning project where I'm adding, on a pre-trained Wide ResNet a couple of linear layers after that, and another technique that I'm using.
My question is if I construct the Network where I add the layers and the techniques that I'm using to the broad resnet as a ModuleList, then I load the pre-trained weights on the entire model with the additions. Does that raise an error in the loading procedure?
Or does it knows that it should only load the weights partially (i.e. only on the reset).
example code:
model = get_model(backbone) # Load ResNet
model = ConstructNewModel(model) # Add layers
load_weights(model, pretrained_path) # load ResNet Weights
model = model.to("cuda") # Add to GPU

or should it look more like this?
model = get_model(backbone) # Load ResNet
load_weights(model, pretrained_path) # load ResNet Weights
model = ConstructNewModel(model) # Add layers
model = model.to("cuda") # Add to GPU

In other words, how does loading the weights in PyTorch work using torch.load?

When loading a custom model which may not be avaialale by default in PyTorch or for any reason has a custom implementation, the first step is to initialise an object of that model, which would contain a supposed "skeleton" of the model, with all the trainable constants, layers, and depending on the implementation, default weights of the edges as well.
The second step then would be to load the state dictionary of the model, which is nothing but a mapping of the values of each and every weight to an actual value. Hence, in such a case you need to specifically intialise the layers since they would be intialised (be assigned weights, independent of pre-trained or actually trained). And then one may shift the model to the device they desire.
In case a model is already available in the Pytorch library (references as a built-in model), such as the resnet50, its weights can be either initialised via values provided by PyTorch:
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights

# Old weights with accuracy 76.130%
resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)

Or a custom dictionary can be fed into the model however that has to be of the same format/layout as required by, in this case, the resnet50 model builder.
Using torch.load() is generally not an accepted way to load models, and rather the dictionary of the model is saved and loaded for the most efficiency and flexibility.
Citing the Pytorch documentation's example here. This is also how I personally save and load my own implementations and till now this approach has been pretty reliable:
# To save the mdoel
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
# To load the model. As I mentioned above, instantiating the model class
# and then loading the state_dict
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()

If I have to shift the model to the GPU, then this is how I do it:
model.load_state_dict(BEST_MODEL_STATE_DICT)
model = model.to(pytorch_dev) if next(model.parameters()).device != pytorch_dev else model

wherein pytorch_dev is selected as the GPU if CUDA is available on the device.
Some good reads may be:

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html
https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.resnet50.html

How the model builder works internally:
https://pytorch.org/vision/master/_modules/torchvision/models/_api.html

thanks for the response, I now understand better how load works, but suppose that I take resent50 from PyTorch and I want to add say 3 MLP layers after that for a certain task I'm working on, these MLP layers have to be trained as well, if I want to take pre trained weights of the resnet50 , model and load them on my new model, does it load like it is supposed to on the new model even though I have extra layers than the resent50?

I cannot think of an elegant way from the top of my head, but you can simply look at the state dictionary of the resnet, assign those weights, and then let the default weights be there on your MLP. I prefer to let the weights be default since I have personally encountered some problems when using for instance a Xavier initialisation. This may help you in the meanwhile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433937/10751129
