# How PyTorch model layer weights get initialized implicitly?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I basically defined a model with a Conv2D and linear layer with PyTorch and trained it with a sample dataset. The model seems to run and converge. But I am wondering I did not explicitly initialize the model layer weights (normal or Xavier). Does that mean when I call model.train() before each epoch training, the layer weights will get initialized randomly by default ? If so, how can I explicitly change the type of initializations ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PyTorch how are layer weights and biases initialized by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529625/in-pytorch-how-are-layer-weights-and-biases-initialized-by-default)

Answer (score 2):

The type of initialization depends on the layer. You can check it from the [`reset_parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear) method or from the docs as well.

For both linear and conv layers, it's He initialization ([`torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_)).

It's mentioned in the documentation as

> The values are initialized from `U(−sqrt(k),sqrt(k))`.

For embedding layer, it's Normal initialization. (mentioned in docs as `N(0,1)`).

---

You can change the type of initialization as mentioned in [How to initialize weights in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433936/how-to-initialize-weights-in-pytorch/49433937#49433937).

```
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(...)
torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(conv1.weight)
```

Comment: "The values are initialized from `U(−sqrt(k), sqrt(k))`." This is Xavier initialization not He. If you check the documentation `k = 1 / in_features`. For He initialization, it should be `k = 2 / in_features`.